# Allowed port 22 with UFW and installed SSHguard but can't SSH

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, ufw

I've installed a new Ubuntu 16.04 with SSHguard (`apt-get install sshguard`), and then enabled UFW:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

I then allowed some ports:

```
sudo ufw allow 22,25,80,443,9000/tcp
```

Yet I can't login from Putty or similar software (such as WinSCP).

When I ping the machine's IP I get a `reply` with `time=63ms` and `TTL=54`.

I fail to understand why SSH locations are blocked: When I try to access the machine with Putty, the background is just blank.

I didn't change anything in the SSHguard configuration.

### Update

After doing a power cycle (restart) from my hosting provider's manage tool, I still can't login, though this time, I do get the option to type a users password.

Comment: Did you install `openssh-server` ?  By default Ubuntu 16.04 only has the client so as to connect to servers, not be the server itself, hence it needs install

Comment: I didn't install it. I have connected with SSH into remote machines many times without installing an `openssh-server`... Are you sure it isn't allowed by default?... Yet, in the last times I connected, I didn't use UFW+SSHguard, rather, CSF-LFD.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html
It could have been dragged into (b/c of deps) by something else you usually install - I'd just check its there & running.  From the machine if you can `ssh localhost` (ie. ssh into itself) ok it'll be fine.